# Windows Server 2008 32 bit & windows 7 professional SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm testing my new Windows Server 2008 32 bit edition (2 servers) as a server and Windows 7 professional 32 bit as a client. Let say one is a primary domain controller (PDC) and the other is a backup domain controller (BDC) like the old time to ease. Every setup were done in the PDC and just replicate to BDC. Didn't setup anything, just install the server with AD, DNS, DHCP, that's all.

Then I use my windows 7 pro 32 bit to join the domain. It worked. After that I tried to change the password of a the user (not administrator) but it always failed said it didn't meet the password complexity setup while in fact there's no setup at all either in account policy, default domain policy or even local policy. Tried to disable the password complexity in the default domain policy instead of didn't set all then test again but still failed.

Browse and found suggestion to setup the minimum and maximum password age to 0 but it also failed.

Tried to restart the server and the client then change password, still failed with the same error, didn't meet password complexity setup.

Tried to see in the rsop.msc but didn't found anything.

In fact, if I see the setup in another system with windows server 2003 and windows xp, using rsop.msc  I can see there's setup for computer configuration > windows settings > security settings > account policies > password policy. I also have a windows 7 pro 32 bit in a windows server 2003 32 bit environment but unable to find the same setting using rsop but this windows 7 works fine.

anyone can give suggestion what's the problem and what to do so I can change my windows 7 pro laptop password in a windows server 2008 environment?

another thing, is it the right assumption that we can see all the policies setting in windows 7 whether it's in a windows server 2003 or 2008 environment?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I set up my domain recently (server is 2008 R2, but running with 2008 domain and forest functional level) the policy "Password must meet complexity requirements" (under Computer Configuration | [...] | Account Policies | Password Policy) *was* enabled by default.

Also remember that GP changes will only be applied with GP refresh cycle (or use `gpupdate.exe` to force a refresh now).